# Is there a way to enable auditing in all entities via sql sever in Dynamics crm?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

In Dynamics Crm I need to enable all auditing in all entities without over each entity one by one.
I need to make a script in sql server to enable auditing in all entities in the   crm. is there a way to enable via sql?

Comment: Could you be more specific with the requirement please.

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I am not squeamish about directly editing CRM tables within SQL, but in this case I **do not** recommend that you take this approach because the audit enabled settings are not a single field that can be easily updated. You can set the entity audit enabled status in bulk through the services using UpdateEntityRequest calls: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327634%28v%3dcrm.8%29

If you do want to poke around at the audit settings in SQL anyway, here is somewhere to start:

```
select name, IsAudited, IsAuditEnabled, e.CanModifyAuditSettings, *
--update e set IsAuditEnabled = 1
from entity e
where e.name in ('contact', 'account') --Set as desired
```

While the above will cause audit to appear to be enabled within CRM solutions, it does NOT successfully enable auditing on the specified tables, so clearly there is more audit related metadata stored elsewhere. **Microsoft does not support manually updating CRM metadata for any reason**.